# How can I update a QTextEdit on another QTabWidget tab?

Tags: qt5

I have two tabs (QTabWidget). On the first tab are the options when checked tell me what text to send to the second tab (in a QTextEdit field). Then I have a QPushButton to generate the text. The problem I have is to send this text to the second tab.

```
FenPrincipale::FenPrincipale(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    ongletGenerateur = new OngletGenerateur(this);
    ongletTexte = new OngletTexte(this);

    tabWidget = new QTabWidget;
    tabWidget->addTab(ongletGenerateur, "Options de génération");
    tabWidget->addTab(ongletTexte, "Texte");

    m_generer = new QPushButton("&Générer !");

    .
    .    layout
    .
    connect(m_generer, &QPushButton::clicked, ongletGenerateur, &OngletGenerateur::genererCode);
}

void OngletGenerateur::genererCode()

{
    .
    .
    .
    texte += "some text";

    ??? how do I send the texte to the second tab (ongletTexte) ???
}
OngletTexte::OngletTexte(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    m_texteGenere = new QTextEdit;
    m_texteGenere->setPlainText("Bla, bla, bla"):
    .
    .
    .
 }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a signal in your `OngletGenerateur` class with one parameter (your string). Emit it from your method. Create a slot in `OngletTexte`. Then, connect the signal and the slot together in `FenPrincipale`.

```
class OngletGenerateur
{
...
signals:
    textGenerated(QString);
};

class OngletTexte
{
...
public slots:
    void append(QString text)
{
    m_texteGenere->append(text);
}
};

FenPrincipale::FenPrincipale(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    connect(ongletGenerateur, &OngletGenerateur::textGenerated, ongletText, &OngletTexte::append);
}
```